# pyQT4 Web Browser Python grant permission (webcam)

Tags: permissions, pyqt, pyqt4, webcam, pyqt5

I need to make a very simple web browser wrapped in python. I am using pyQt4 for this. I can very easily create a little browser to load web pages and almost everything works fine. The issue I am having is that accessing the webcam does not work. Navigating to any url that attempts to access the webcam (through javascript getUserMedia() ) does nothing. Doesn't even prompt for the user to select a webcam device.

Why is this?

How do I grant permission to use the webcam with a simple pyQT4 python program?

Here is what I have so far:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit


class myWindow(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        #self.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myWindow", self)

        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_loadFinished)

        self.page().featurePermissionRequested.connect(self.permissionRequested)

        self.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://pubnub.com/developers/demos/webrtc'))


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_loadFinished(self):
        #self.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(getJsValue)

    def permissionRequested(self, frame, feature):
        self.page().setFeaturePermission(frame, feature, QWebPage.PermissionGrantedByUser)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myWindow')

    main = myWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code loads a webrtc demo which should immediately prompt for webcam access. But it does not. All websites that ask for webcam permissions do not work.

Note:
I tried to define permission request and then grant access. However, it still does nothing. I could be doing something wrong here?

Thanks for any help you guys can provide. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

QtWebKit only supports [Geolocation and Notifications](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebpage.html#Feature-enum) as permission requests.

I don't think it supports WebRTC at all, you might want to upgrade to PyQt5 and use [QtWebEngine](http://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine) instead.

Comment: Ok so I should use PyQt5. Do you know of any good tutorials for a very simple browser, like the one I have above for PyQt4? Thanks